# C++ Read characters in only one line

Tags: c++, end-of-line

I want to read only the characters from the first line of a file and then stop.
The following code is not working in Codeblocks because the output file is empty.
What did I do wrong?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream cin ("test.in");
ofstream cout ("test.out");
char s;
int main()
{
while (cin>>s)
if (s=='\n')
{
cout<<"end of line"; return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot catch an end of line like that. Have a look at `getline`

Comment: Try `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);` Here is a full example: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Thanks. Getline is not working because the no. of characters on that line is too high and I'm running out of the time limit for the code to run.

Comment: What is the size of your line ?

Comment: 1000000 characters

Comment: You can preallocate the string before you start. From my example put line.reserve(1000000); before std::getline(). With that said this may require a different solution because they may time smaller inputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code, but the one that stops it working is that `>>` cannot be used to read whitespace characters, they are just ignored by this operator, so `s` will never equal `'\n'`.

Fortunately wanting to read a single line is a very common requirement and there's already a function `getline` which does exactly that. Here's your program rewritten to use `getline` and with all the other various issues fixed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("test.in");
    std::ofstream out("test.out");
    std::string line;
    if (getline(in, line))
        out << "end of line\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but.getline is not working because the no. of characters on that line is too high and I'm running out of the time limit for the code to run

Comment: @Abacus It won't be getline that is causing your time limit to be exceeded, it will be the rest of your code.

Comment: @Abacus And in any case what makes you think that reading characters one at a time would be any faster?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'll try again with getline. However, there is no other way to read characters one by one until the end of the line?

Comment: @Abacus You can use `in.get()` which will read exactly one character, even if it's a whitespace character.

Comment: And how do you stop get() at the end of the line?

Comment: A TLE is most likely caused by some other part of your code. Reading character by character if anything will be slower than reading a line at a time.

Comment: @Abacus Just as you were `if (s == '\n')`